# PHP Select Statement - Errors

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am student and I work on a noteapp. I made 2 methods in my DB-Handler within my Login-Mask for users to Login or Register.

```
    <?php


    class DBHandler
    {

var $hostname;
var $user;
var $pw;
var $db;

var $connection;

function connectToDB($hostname,$user,$pw,$db){
    $this->hostname = $hostname;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pw = $pw;
    $this->db = $db;

    $this->connection = new mysqli($this->hostname,$this->user,$this->pw,$this->db);

    if ($this->connection->connect_error) {
        die('Failed to connect' . $this->connection->connect_error);
    }

    $this->ensureNotesTable();
    $this->ensureUsersTable();
}

function ensureUsersTable(){
    assert($this->connection);

    $queryCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INT(5) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)";
    $this->connection->query($queryCreate);
}

function ensureNotesTable(){
    assert($this->connection);

    $queryCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notesnew(id INT(5) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, content VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, userid INT(5) NOT NULL)";
    $this->connection->query($queryCreate);
}

function ensureUsername($username,$password){
    assert($this->connection);

    echo $username;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (?)";
    $statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('s',$username);
    $results = $statement->execute();
    echo $this->connection->errno.'-'.$this->connection->error;

    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1){
        echo $this->connection->errno.'-'.$this->connection->error;
        echo "Username already exists";
    } echo "Username is free!";
        $this->addUser($username,$password);
}


function addUser($username,$password){
    assert($this->connection);

    $queryCreate = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
    $statement = $this->connection->prepare($queryCreate);
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);

    return $statement->execute();

    echo "You have been registered!";
}

function getUserId($username){
    assert($this->connection);

    $queryCreate = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = $username";
    $row = $this->connection->query($queryCreate);

    $userid = mysqli_fetch_row($row);
    return $userid[0];
}

function addNote($title, $text, $userID){
    assert($this->connection);

    $queryCreate = "INSERT INTO notesnew(title, content, userid) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $statement = $this->connection->prepare($queryCreate);
    $statement->bind_param('ssi', $title,$text,$userID);

    return $statement->execute();
}
```

}

Within ensureUsername I wanna check if the username which is used for the registration has already been picked by another user.

Within addUser I wanna do the Insert statement, to add the user to the database, if the username is free.

I tried about 3 hours today but it always gives me errors. I hate it! Maybe im just too stupid for it.

At the moment its saying:

> Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given in
>   C:\Users\ReallySorry\PhpstormProjects\NoteAppMongo\DBHandler.php on
>   line 57 0- Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, null given in
>   C:\Users\ReallySorry\PhpstormProjects\NoteAppMongo\DBHandler.php on
>   line 60

Does anybody know what im doing wrong?

Thanks ...

The depressed student

Comment: You're having problems, it's true, but you know what? I've seen so many people here just shoving PHP variables directly into SQL statements that it makes me fear for the future of web development. You are already *very far* ahead of the pack, so don't worry about hitting small problems along the way: you're doing a great job!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
$statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('s',$username);
$results = $this->connection->query($statement)
```

When you're using prepared statements (well done – so many people here don't!) you need to use the `execute()` method on your statement rather than calling `query()` on your connection. So, this should work:

```
$results = $statement->execute()
```

Comment: Wrote almost identical answer, that's the way to go.

Comment: Thats what i originally tried, yes, but then i get the following errors:

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Users\ReallySorry\PhpstormProjects\NoteAppMongo\DBHandler.php on line 60 Username is free! Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\Users\ReallySorry\PhpstormProjects\NoteAppMongo\DBHandler.php on line 73

Comment: You can't use `mysqli_num_rows()` here, I'm afraid. Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to be certain, but I suspect you should use `num_rows` as [shown here](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I added the full DBHandler class, maybe it helps to identify the mistake. Thanks for the answers till now :)

Comment: Did you try using `num_rows` as I suggested? That link I provided does give the exact example you want.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor changes to the original -

```
function ensureUsername( $username=false, $password=false ){
    $rv=false;/* Return Value */
    if( !assert( $this->connection ) or !$username or !$password ) return $rv;
    $db=$this->connection;/* shorthand for laziness */


    $sql = "select `username` from `users` where `username`=?;";
    $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username );
    $res = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if( $res ){
        $rv=( $stmt->num_rows > 0 ) ? 'Sorry, that Username already exists!' : $this->addUser( $username, $password );
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
    echo $rv;
}


function addUser( $username, $password ){
    $db=$this->connection;/* No need for assert now, if the script gets here the db conn must exist */

    $sql = "insert into `users` (`username`, `password`) values (?,?);";
    $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password );

    return $stmt->execute() ? 'You have been registered!' : 'Sorry, there was a problem';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i copy & paste that code it says: Use of undefined function execute()

Comment: Sorry `ReallySorry` - I had attached the execute to the wrong object.

Comment: I still get a 

"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\ReallySorry\PhpstormProjects\NoteAppMongo\DBHandler.php on line 60"

at the line:

        if ($result->num_rows >= 1){

Comment: ah-silly me. The returned result from `$stmt->execute()` is either true or false, not a recordset ~ should have seen that before. I've made some edits above - hopefully that should help...

Comment: Its working xD I hope the problems i had are not too stupid... Thank you much for your time.